# Filter rows from group by clause postgresql

Tags: sql, filter, group-by, postgresql-12

I have below table, Now I want `group by on col_1`, and want to select data of that group which has  `col_2='ValueNet' and col_3='no'` and also want to exclude row which satisfy before said condition. (i.e col_2='ValueNet' and col_3='no')

```
col_1  | col_2     |   col_3 <br>
1     | Community1 |  ACSNET    
1     | Community2 |  ACSNET    
1     | ValueNet   |  yes   
2     | Community3 |  ACSNET    
2     | Community4 |  ACSNET    
2     | ValueNet   |  no
```

my result table should be:

```
col_1    | col_2    |   col_3 <br>
2     | Community3 |  ACSNET    
2     | Community4 |  ACSNET
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to make a query that finds from the table all the results according to the condition you mention: "col_2='ValueNet' and col_3='no'", and then to make an except clause for what you want to exclude:

```
select * from [Table_1] where col_1 in
(select col_1 from [Table_1] 
where col_2 ='ValueNet' and col_3='no')
except
(select * from [Table_1] 
 where col_2 ='ValueNet' and col_3='no')
```